# How can I show the first item, toggle-ready on angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to show the detail of the first item in ng-repeat, toggle-ready with angularjs.

In the code you can see the detail of the first button shows, but cant toggle like other buttons.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-repeat="i in ['I want to toggle', 'toggle 2', 'toggle 3', 'toggle 4']">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a ng-click="showDetail = !showDetail"> <!-- toggle here -->
              <input type='button' value='{{i}}' />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="showDetail || $first">----Detail!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean that you want the first time to show on the initial load, and then control it with button like others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of this line `<div ng-show="showDetail || $first">----Detail!</div>`. This is saying the first item will always be visible. Use `ng-init` to set `showDetail` based on whether it is first and it should work.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-repeat="i in ['I want to toggle', 'toggle 2', 'toggle 3', 'toggle 4']" 
       ng-init="showDetail = $first ? true : false">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a ng-click="showDetail = !showDetail"> <!-- toggle here -->
              <input type='button' value='{{i}}' />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="showDetail">----Detail!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew $first was making the first always showing, but I write it cause you can understand better the question....thank you very much : )

Answer (score 0):

create a list of objects and init them before the ng-repeat in the div above or so, then set the show hide inside the object, to make it state aware

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-init="items=[{text:'I want to toggle',showDetail:true}, {text:'toggle 2',showDetail:false}, {text:'toggle 3',showDetail:false}, {text:'toggle 4',showDetail:false}]">
  <div ng-repeat="i in items">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <a ng-click="i.showDetail = !i.showDetail"> <!-- toggle here -->
              <input type='button' value='{{i.text}}' />
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div ng-show="i.showDetail">----Detail!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```